# (Stata) Find values from earlier years with multiple observations within a year

Tags: stata

I'm using Stata. I have a dataset of multiple firms and their banks within a given year for multiple years. Since firms often have more than one bank there's multiple observations for a firm-year. I have a variable "bank_exityear" which contains the last year a bank is in the sample. I would like to create a variable that for each firm within a given year contains the minimum of "bank_exityear" from the previous year (and for the same firm).

An example data-set is attached here:

[image]

The variable I'd like to create is the bold "want". The data starts in 2008.

What would be the best way to create this variable?

Comment: You should install `dataex` from ssc. This is much easier for everyone than posting images of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `rangestat` (from SSC). To install it, type in Stata's Command window:

```
ssc install rangestat
```

For the problem at hand, this requires finding the minimum **bank_exityear** across all observations of the same **firmid** whose **year** is one less than the year of the current observation:

```
clear
input year firmid bankid bank_exityear want
2008 1 1 2008 .
2008 1 2 2015 .
2009 1 2 2015 2008
2009 1 3 2015 2008
2010 1 2 2015 2015
2010 1 3 2015 2105
end

rangestat (min) bank_exityear, interval(year -1 -1) by(firmid)
list
```

and the results:

```
. list, sepby(firmid)

     +-----------------------------------------------------+
     | year   firmid   bankid   bank_e~r   want   bank_e~n |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2008        1        1       2008      .          . |
  2. | 2008        1        2       2015      .          . |
  3. | 2009        1        2       2015   2008       2008 |
  4. | 2009        1        3       2015   2008       2008 |
  5. | 2010        1        2       2015   2015       2015 |
  6. | 2010        1        3       2015   2105       2015 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

This sort of strategy might do the trick:

```
clear
input year firmid bankid bank_exityear want
2008 1 1 2008 .
2008 1 2 2015 .
2009 1 2 2015 2008
2009 1 3 2015 2008
2010 1 2 2015 2015
2010 1 3 2015 2105
end

tempfile min_year
preserve
    collapse (min) want2 = bank_exityear, by(firmid year)
    save `min_year' 
restore

replace year = year - 1
merge m:1 firmid year using "`min_year'", nogen keep(master match)
replace year = year + 1
```

This assumes that there are no gaps in year.

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little bit unclear but I believe some combination of

```
bysort bank_id (year) : gen lag_exit = bank_exit_year[_n-1]
bysort bank_id : egen min_var = min(lag_exit )
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't create the variable I need, as the indexation _n-1 only goes one observation back and thus might not capture all observations for the firm in t-1. I need to retrieve the minimum of bankexit_year across all observations in t-1 for each firm.